# youtube analytics api returns Daily Limit Exceeded error, when data api hits the limit

Tags: google-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

I am using youtube data api v3 and youtube analytics api for my project. 
data api's quota is 10,000 and analytics api's quota is 1,200. 
I rarely use analytics api currently, so it only hits 0.02% of quota.

I today found that analytics api returns 'Daily Limit Exceeded' error. I checked it on google console, and of course there is no problem. It still has enough space. 
However, when I check my data api I found that data api hits the limit.

Does  that mean all APIs in the same project share usage of quota? or I'am missing something important here..